# Объединение двух объектов

Tags: jquery, javascript, angularjs

Javascript, объединение двух объектов.
Сейчас делаю так:

```
jQuery.extend({}, obj1, obj2);
```

Работает не как надо, т.к. `obj1`, `obj2` такого вида:

```
obj1 = {child_obj,child_obj,child_obj,child_obj,child_obj};
obj2 = {child_obj,child_obj,child_obj,child_obj,child_obj};
```

В результате получаю типа этого:

```
Object {0: Object, 1: Object, 2: Object, 3: Object, 4: Object}
```

Проблема в том, что мне не нужна нумерация новых объектов, а чтобы было все, как в `obj1`, `obj2`, только уже объединенное.

Спасибо.

Comment: Попробуйте

    jQuery.extend(true, {}, obj1, obj2); // deep copy


P.S. С Angular не работаю, но поиск обнаружил и там метод [`.extend(src, dst)`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.extend).

Comment: @Fikret, сделай пример на jsfiddle, увидишь, что не работает, как ты написал.